# Looking for the heap pointer of a String

Tags: rust

I'm trying to obtain the heap pointer to a String. Here is my code:

```
fn main() {
   let mut s1 = String::with_capacity(25);
   s1.push_str("Hello");

   unsafe {
      let string_ref= &s1;
      println!("string_reference: {:p}", string_ref);
    
      let stack_ptr = string_ref as *const String as *const usize;
      println!("stack_ptr: {:p}", stack_ptr);
    
      println!("heap_ptr through method: {:p}", s1.as_ptr());
      let heap_ptr = *stack_ptr as *const usize;
      println!("heap_ptr through pointer: {:p}", heap_ptr);
  }
}
```

Here you can find the [code on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=677d1a8e39211825861cc0c0f5a7b6cb)

The most curious is that this code does well in one of my computers, but not in the other nor in Playground.

Comment: "I'm trying to obtain the heap pointer to a String." that doesn't mean anything. What are you looking for, the pointer to the heap buffer for the string data? `s1.as_ptr()`, `s1.as_str()` or `&*s1` will all work, and none of them requires unsafe.

Comment: Your first two data dumps are the same pointer to the stack location of the `String` object itself (string is a structure around a pointer), the third one is correct, the last one is absolute nonsense as it basically just interprets whatever is laid out at the start of the stack structure as a pointer then prints that. Since Rust does not guarantee struct layouts unless `repr(C)`, it could be uninitialised memory, it could be the pointer, it could be the length, or it could be the capacity.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the order of the fields of a struct in the stack is not guaranteed

Comment: The order of the fields is not guaranteed regardless of where it's stored.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the internals of String anyway?

Comment: Well, I'm playing and having fun while trying to learn

Comment: What might also be interesting to look at: [`String::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_raw_parts)

Comment: @PitaJ The unstable `into_raw_parts()` is just a shortcut for separately getting `as_mut_ptr()`, `len()`, and `capacity()`.